# What's the maximum file size for 9GAG uploads?

Tags: 9gag

I can't find it anywhere.

What's the maximum file size when trying to upload a picture on http://9gag.com/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since nobody seems to know this, I tested it out myself:

`5,242,881 B` is too big, `5,242,876 B` is accepted. That is `5242880/1024/1024 = 5 MB` max exactly

Comment: It is ~12 MB for videos now. Use handbrake and convert your video to 480p. That should do it.

Comment: It is ~20 MB for videos by now. I could upload a 19,5 MB video today but not one with 20,5 MB.

Answer (score 0):

- 20mb for videos
- 5mb for GIFs

Images are probably 5mb too

Comment: This is not true

Comment: @MariánZekeŠedaj Prove it, post a new answer here and I will delete this.